# Exact dismax search in multivalue field with spaces

Tags: solr

I'm trying to add tags to user-provided text in order to automagically classify the article.

It works pretty well except for words with spaces.
For instance, I want to add the "clothes" tag when user type the following words in that order: "tee shirt" or "tee shirts".
The sentence "my tee shirt is blue" should brings a result since "tee shirt" is written correctly in that order but neither "tee my shirt" nor "my shirt" should return a result.

I have a dedicated "tags" core to do that.
I create an empty core with

```
  /opt/solr/bin/solr create -c "tags"
```

and update the core schema using curl

```
  curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{ "add-field-type" : { "name":"myShingleTextField", "class":"solr.TextField", "positionIncrementGap":"100", "analyzer" : { "tokenizer":{ "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" }, "filters":[ { "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" }, { "class":"solr.ShingleFilterFactory", "maxShingleSize":"3",  "outputUnigrams":"true" }, ]}} }' http://localhost:8983/solr/tags/schema
  curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{ "add-field": { "name":"keywords", "type":"myShingleTextField", "multiValued":true, "indexed":true, "stored":true, "required":true, "docValues":false } }' http://localhost:8983/solr/tags/schema
  curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{ "add-field": { "name":"results", "type":"string", "multiValued":true, "indexed":true, "stored":true, "required":true, "docValues":true } }' http://localhost:8983/solr/tags/schema
```

I then /update it with the following (simplified) document:

```
{ "add": { "doc": { "keywords": ["tee shirt", "tee shirts"], "results": ["clothes"] } }, "commit": { } }
```

I finally do my query:

```
/select?defType=dismax&q=tee%20my%20shirt&qf=keywords
```

It return a document while I don't want one ("my" between "tee" and "shirt").

Maybe it's a tokenizer issue or maybe dismax query is not what I need.
I tried escaping quotes or spaces, modifying the mm parameter to 2 (which kinda works but prevents one-word to match) and other tweaking that didn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Sound like you want to search for a phrase, have you tried wrapping the `q=` argument with quotes?

Comment: Not really.

The "q" parameter is set to whatever the user types. If user types "my tee shirt is blue", I will search that string (with quotes) and solr will return nothing while tee shirt words are correctly ordered.

If I add a document with a single word, like keywords="airmax" results="shoes" it works fine.

Comment: Does the same rule hold for longer sentences? I.e. are you always looking for exact phrase matches against what's in the index? A shingle filter on query and single tokens when indexing would possibly solve that. The shingle filter on indexing would generate `tee`, `tee_my`, `tee_my_shirt`, `my_shirt`, while the index would contain `tee_shirt`. Neither would generate a match. The indexing would be a keywordtokenizer with lowercaser and a regular expression to replace whitespace with `_`

Comment: `Does the same rule hold for longer sentences? I.e. are you always looking for exact phrase matches against what's in the index?`

Yes, I query solr with a long sentence and I want to find keywords (exact match) in it.

`The shingle filter on indexing would generate...`

I guess you wanted to type "on querying" here.

I was not aware I could use a shingle filter on a query.
I think your proposed solution will work, thanks for the hint!
I'll test that (probably this weekend) and mark your answer as valid if it turns out you're right.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MatsLindth hints, I came up with a solution.

First, I needed to replace spaces in multiple words by '_' and to use a KeywordTokenizerFactory tokenizer to store them verbatim.
On the query side, I had to specify "tokenSeparator" parameter as '_'.

So my custom field type definition command is now :

```
  curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{ "add-field-type" : { "name":"myShingleTextField", "class":"solr.TextField", "positionIncrementGap":"100", "indexAnalyzer": { "tokenizer":{ "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" } }, "queryAnalyzer" : { "tokenizer":{ "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" }, "filters":[ { "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" }, { "class":"solr.ShingleFilterFactory", "maxShingleSize":"3",  "outputUnigrams":"true", "tokenSeparator":"_" }, ]}} }' http://localhost:8983/solr/tags/schema
```

My update command is now:

```
{ "add": { "doc": { "keywords": ["tee_shirt", "tee_shirts"], "results": ["clothes"] } }, "commit": { } }
```

So when I do :

```
/select?defType=dismax&q=tee%20my%20shirt&qf=keywords
```

we have

"tee my shirt"

"tee" "my" "shirt" (StandardTokenizerFactory + LowerCaseFilterFactory)

"tee" "tee_my" "tee_my_shirt" "my" "my_shirt" "shirt" (ShingleFilterFactory)

Nothing matches as expected but querying "my tee shirt" brings "tee_shirt" which obviously matches "tee_shirt", yay!

Thanks again to @MatsLindth and Solr analysis page!